# Display grid on basis of Enquiry No

Tags: sql, asp.net, oracle

The below query displays me the result which I want to show in the grid.

```
SELECT bb.project_id, bb.building_id, bb.flat_id AS flat_id,
   cc.cust_enq_no AS enquiry_no, cc.NAME enquiry_name,
   TO_CHAR (cc.f_followup_date, 'dd/MM/yyyy') AS last_followup_date,
   cc.f_remarks AS last_followup_comments  FROM xxacl_pn_flat_det_v bb INNER JOIN xxcus.xxacl_pn_customer_enquiry_v cc
   ON bb.project_id = cc.mkey
```

but there is some change in my requirement.

Now for each `F_FLAT_ID` there is multiple `CUST_ENQ_NO` say

```
Select * from xxcus.xxacl_pn_customer_enquiry_v where F_FLAT_ID = '18158'
```

it has 3 records.

So with my first query,

> How to get multiple CUST_ENQ_NO

**UPDATE**

I want to filter and display it in the grid

```
protected void DisplayGridEnquiry()
{
    OracleCommand cmd1 = new OracleCommand("SELECT bb.project_id, bb.building_id, bb.flat_id as FLAT_ID, cc.cust_enq_no as ENQUIRY_NO, " +
                                           "cc.NAME ENQUIRY_NAME, TO_CHAR (cc.f_followup_date,'dd/MM/yyyy') as LAST_FOLLOWUP_DATE, cc.f_remarks AS LAST_FOLLOWUP_COMMENTS " +
                                           "FROM xxacl_pn_flat_det_v bb INNER JOIN xxcus.xxacl_pn_customer_enquiry_v cc " +
                                           "ON bb.project_id = cc.mkey", ObjPriCon);
    DataTable dtfillgrid1 = new DataTable();
    OracleDataAdapter da1 = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd1);
    da1.Fill(dtfillgrid1);

    DataView dView1 = new DataView(dtfillgrid1);
    dView1.RowFilter = "PROJECT_ID = '" + ddlProject.SelectedValue + "' AND BUILDING_ID = '" + ddlBuilding.SelectedValue + "' AND FLAT_ID = '" + ddlUnit.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
    GridEnquiry.DataSource = dView1.ToTable();
    GridEnquiry.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT bb.project_id, bb.building_id, bb.flat_id AS flat_id,
   cc.cust_enq_no AS enquiry_no, cc.NAME enquiry_name,
   TO_CHAR (cc.f_followup_date, 'dd/MM/yyyy') AS last_followup_date,
   cc.f_remarks AS last_followup_comments  
FROM xxacl_pn_flat_det_v bb 
LEFT JOIN xxcus.xxacl_pn_customer_enquiry_v cc ON  bb.flat_id=cc.F_FLAT_ID
```

Comment: with the above query, I am just getting `FLAT_NO` . no `cust_enq_no`

Comment: try using full outer join instead of left join.
it would be better to understand if you specify your relationships between this 2 table

Comment: same thing is happening, no `CUST_ENQ_NO` is coming with full outer join also

Comment: actually i want to show multiple cust_enq_no on the filter of `dView1.RowFilter = "PROJECT_ID = '" + ddlProject.SelectedValue + "' AND BUILDING_ID = '" + ddlBuilding.SelectedValue + "' AND FLAT_ID = '" + ddlUnit.SelectedItem.Text + "'";` I have updated my question